# HP designjet 500 printhead allignment issue

Tags: printing, printer

After replacing the printheads,the machine flashes the exclamation mark on the
yellow printhead saying that it is worn out (on the new printhead). All
of the other ones have their status as "inserted". Since acquiring the
printer, we replaced the belt, the interconnect cable, the ink tube
system, and the ink supply station. The printer finally prints, but the
patterns come out like this (the pattern appears to be staggered by 1 mm)
[image] and the machine says it failed to
align the printheads. When the carriage moves, it seems as though there
is a slight lag between how the belt pulls the carriage and its
movement. What should we do to proceed?

The machine is a designjet 500 42".

[image]

links:
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Designjet-Large-Format/HP-designjet-500-printhead-allignment-issue-staggered-pattern/td-p/6485552#.U3-s_yjHnoU

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printing-Issues-Troubleshooting/HP-designjet-500-printhead-allignment-issue-staggered/m-p/3943490/highlight/false#M88792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend, i had the same problem. I had to change the belt. 
After open the plotter and put the new belt, i've tried to allign the printheads, and it failed. 
My patterns was the same as the ones in your image.

After trying a lot of things, i i've remembered that the carriage had two small plastic pieces, between the carriage and the metal bar, where the carriage moves. Finally, I flip those two pieces upside down, and it gaves the carriage a lot more stability. That simple flip on those plastic "rings" solve my problem.

Hope that this helps you.